# Get values from array within another array

Tags: php

Here is my array that prints to screen.

```
    Array
( 
    [original_title] => My Title
    [genres] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 18
                    [name] => Drama
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 14
                    [name] => Fantasy
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10756
                    [name] => Indie
                )

        )

    [vote_average] => 6.8
    [vote_count] => 11
)
```

I am able to pull the values from the initial array like so:

```
echo"<br>Title: ";
print_r($pelinfo['original_title']);
```

Which outputs **Title: My Title**

I want to be able to add all genres by name.

**Genres: Drama, Fantasy, Indie**

Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/language.control-structures.php).

In this case, a [`foreach`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) works nicely:

```
foreach($pelinfo['genres'] as $genre) {
   echo $genre['name'];
}
```

To output the exact format (with commas), you could build another array and use [`implode()`](http://php.net/implode) (per **Patrick Evans**). My goal was to teach.

Comment: Thanks! that is understandable.

Answer (score 1):

```
$Genres = array();
foreach( $pelinfo["genres"] as $Genre ) {
   $Genres[] = $Genre["name"];
}

echo "Genres:".implode(", ",$Genres);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [foreach](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php)

```
foreach ($pelinfo['genres'] as $genre)
{
    echo $genre['name'];
}
```